# Carving a wood bowl or cut without a lathe

Tags: drilling, turning, carving

My son wants to make my wife a wooden bowl or cup out of a section of a log.  I don't have a lathe and was wondering if its possible to hollow it out using some type of drill bit or sanding disc on a drill attachment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how deep the cup/bowl will be you may be able to carve it out with a large gouge, hook knife, or scorp.

I would also look into power carving options, such as a burr on a Foredom-style tool, or the arbortech "mini turbo" or "turbo shaft".

With any of these options, though, I think you'd still want to hog out as much waste as possible with a drill press.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more research I think that using a forstner bit would be my best option

Comment: A couple of points worth noting, a Forstner bit won't leave a completely flat bottom and you'll be creating vertical-sided holes unless you can tilt the workpiece or drill-press table (while keeping the work very firmly clamped). For both these reasons expect to have to do quite a bit of follow-on handwork to complete the shaping. Also you'll want to keep the side walls of anything like this thick for the drilling stage and thin down after if needed, otherwise you risk blowing out the outer wall as you drill.